# NServiceBus with RabbitMQ Simple event

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus

I want to be able to used NServiceBus to add a message on a queue in RabbitMQ. I dont want to handle it yet so just want to see an item on the queue, my code is as follows, but I get this error when I run it?

I have been trying to look at the documentation but is seems overly confusing. I am familar with RabbitMq and using it as is or with the Rabbit client library, but NService bus seems to complicate and confuse the situation!

[image]

```
using Shared;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NServiceBus.RabbitMqTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("UserChanged");
            var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>();
            transport.UseConventionalRoutingTopology();
            transport.ConnectionString("host=localhost;username=guest;password=guest");

            //transport.Routing().RouteToEndpoint(typeof(MyCommand), "Samples.RabbitMQ.SimpleReceiver");
            endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

            var endpointInstance = await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).ConfigureAwait(false);

            await SendMessages(endpointInstance);

            //await endpointInstance.Publish(new UserChanged { UserId = 76 });
            
            await endpointInstance.Stop().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        static async Task SendMessages(IMessageSession messageSession)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press [e] to publish an event. Press [Esc] to exit.");
            while (true)
            {
                var input = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();

                switch (input.Key)
                {
                    //case ConsoleKey.C:
                    //    await messageSession.Send(new MyCommand());
                    //    break;
                    case ConsoleKey.E:
                        await messageSession.Publish(new UserChanged { UserId = 87 });
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                        return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your endpoint is publishing the message as well as receiving it. Since there's no handler defined to handle the `UserChanged` messages (events), NServiceBus recoverability kicks in. Your options are

1. Declare the endpoint as [send-only](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/#self-hosting-send-only-hosting) to avoid handling the messages when there are no handlers defined
2. Define a [handler](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/handlers/) for `UserChanged`